# Adds an empty value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backand

For some reason my back end adds an empty value when I press the button Add. I don't know the reason... I tried to debug it by console.log() in its callback it gives me the actual string I inputed....? What is wrong?

Basically if you are still confused: it adds the value.. But it adds an empty string. This is a todo app

index.html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!-- Backand SDK for Angular -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="//cdn.backand.net/backand/dist/1.8.2/backand.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller = "AppCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">My Backand Todo List</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="has-header">
    <input type="text" placeholder="New Todo" id = "todo" ng-model = "description"/>
    <input type = "button" ng-click = "create();" value = "ADD"/>
    <ion-list can-swipe="true">
       <ion-item ng-repeat="item in todos">
         {{item.name}}
         <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="delete(item.id)">
           Delete
         </ion-option-button>
       </ion-item>
     </ion-list>



  </ion-content>

  </body>
</html>
```

App.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'backand'])

.config(function (BackandProvider) {
  BackandProvider.setAppName('todos');
  BackandProvider.setAnonymousToken('6956403d-1b7c-4455-9539-df04125f2c70');
})

.controller('AppCtrl', ["$scope", "TodoService","$http","Backand" ,function($scope, TodoService, $http, Backand) {
  $scope.create = function () {
  var newTodo =  {'description': $('#todo').val()}
      return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url : Backand.getApiUrl() + '/1/objects/' + 'todos',
        data: newTodo,
        params: {
          returnObject: true
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        getTodo();
        console.log($("#todo").val())
        return response.data;
      });
    };

     function getTodo (){
      TodoService.getTodos()
        .then(function (result) {
          $scope.todos = result.data.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.delete = function (todo) {
          return $http({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url : Backand.getApiUrl() +  '/1/objects/' + 'todos' + '/' + todo
          }).then(function(response) {
            console.log( response.data );
            getTodo();
          });
        };
getTodo()
}]
)


.service('TodoService', function ($http, Backand) {
  var baseUrl = '/1/objects/';
  var objectName = 'todos';

  function getUrl() {
    return Backand.getApiUrl() + baseUrl + objectName;
  }

  function getUrlForId(id) {
    return getUrl() + id;
  }

  getTodos = function () {
    return $http.get(getUrl());
  };

  addTodo = function(todo) {
    return $http.post(getUrl(), todo);
  }

  deleteTodo = function (id) {
    return $http.delete(getUrlForId(id));
  };

  return {
    getTodos: getTodos,
    addTodo: addTodo,
    deleteTodo: deleteTodo
  }
});
```

Comment: It adds the value.. But it adds a empty string. @isherwood its a todoapp

Comment: can you send the network tab in chrom(F12)